# How to pass all bash env variables to cron

Tags: bash, cron, env

A given crontab entry gives errors and the reason is that it can not read all env variables from bash. I wonder how could I pass all this info to cron

Comment: To the "off-topic" closer: I'll think you'll find that both (1) `bash` is a programming language as well as a user shell; and (2) `cron` is a tool commonly used by programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick I've used in the past is to open up a bash session for the specific user and just type:

```
env >$HOME/.cronenv
```

You can this source this file from your cron scripts (or directly from the crontabs if you're running an executable you can't change) with something like:

```
. $HOME/.cronenv
```

This is, of course, using a thermonuclear warhead to kill a fly. You should really identify the bare minimum that your script requires and just use that.